# Attach souces в netbeans

Tags: maven, java, netbeans

Не могу понять, как в мой netbeans приделать исходный код стороннего проекта - struts 2. Мне нужно, чтобы я во время написания своего кода мог просматривать код самого struts прямо в IDE.
Пытался решать несколькими способами:

1) скачал с сайта apache полный архив струтса (struts-2.3.16.3-all.zip), но как задеплоить ЭТО в свой репозиторий вместе с сорцами, так и непонял;

2) прописал GAV кое-какого артефакта струтса в pom.xml своего проекта:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
            <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.16.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

Теперь я создал наследникa, например, класса `com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionChainResult;` и хочу посмотреть исходный код. В результате в NetBeanse, конечно же, никакой исходный код не отображается. Сами сорцы я-то скачал с сайта apache. Но вот как прикрутить их к репозиторию, если эти сорцы являются простым набором пакетов и .java файлов?

В NetBeanse я нажал на кнопку  attach souces и указал на тот архив с сорцами, который я скачал, но результата нет. Потом я распаковал этот архив и указал уже папку с .java пакетами. Результата тоже не случилось.

P.S. Однако нажал на кнопку dowload в окне attach sources, и моя IDE сама загрузила эти сорцы и  положила их в репозиторий. Я хочу на будущее знать, есть ли нормальный способ указать в pom.xml так, чтобы в репозиторий скачивались артефакты с сорцами?

Comment: добавьте кто нибудь предыдущий комментарий в ОТВЕТЫ. я хочу пометить его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите вот этот пост http://tedwise.com/2010/01/27/maven-micro-tip-get-sources-and-javadocs/